# How can i add a copy right/license to my book online

Tags: ebook-readers, publishing, copyright, license

I have being writing a book which i am planning to publish but i don't have a copy right/license. I was asking of how to do that online.

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this would be better on law stackexchange

Answer (score 1):

In many countries you don't need to register a copyright, but it is automatically granted to you. Therefore it is probably unnecessary for you to do anything. Typically you can declare it on the title page of the book.